# Can anyone tell me how i can create a jump menu in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp

Can anyone tell me how i can create a jump menu in cakephp?

Answer (score 0):

There's a CakePHP tutorial that may be of some help to you.  See http://www.cakephp-it.org/topic255-pippoacl.html for details.  It's written in Italian, so you may want to use Google's translator service (http://translate.google.com/?hl=en#) to read it.